# no main classes not found

Tags: java, class, methods

I have few classes in my project.the main class should me SMSMain.But when i run the project it gives no main class found error.I tried to set in in properties(Netbeans) but it doesn't find any.where am I going wrong?here is my code:

```
package 
na.edu.pon.oop210s.s12012.s211045888.sms;
/**
 * Student Number: <211045888>
 * Date: 3/11/12 7:47 pM
 * Exercise: <Exercise 4>
 * Created using: <netbeans>
 */


 public class sms {

 class Student 
{
    int   studentID;
    String studentName,course;

public  void        setName(String studentName){
this.studentName = studentName;
}
public  void        setNewId(int studentID){
this.studentID = studentID;
}

public  void        setCourse(String course){
 this.course = course;
}
public  String      toString(){
return studentID +" "+studentName.toString();

}
    class lecturer{
        int staffID;
        String staffName,taughtCourses;

        public  void        setName(String staffName){
this.staffName = staffName;
}
public  void        setNewId(int staffID){
this.staffID = staffID;
                 }
public  String      toString(){
return staffID +" "+staffName.toString();

}
        class course{
            String code,description;
            double units;

course(String code, String CD){
this.code=code.toUpperCase();
description=CD.toUpperCase();
}
public String getCode(){
return code;

                       }


/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public class SMSMain {
public  void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Student a = new Student();
    a.studentName = "Maria";
    a.studentID = 1236;
    System.out.println("Student Name:" + a.studentName);
    System.out.println("Student Name:" + a.studentID);

 }
}



        }}}}
```

Comment: See the answers. And place the class SMSMain in its own SMSMain.java.

Comment: I have placed the SMSMain in own file,it's looking ok but now the other classes are in the other file and can't be found on the main class file. do I need to insert them as well?

Comment: Better yes, Student.java etcetera.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use

```
public static void main(String[] args){/* ... */}
```

with the `static` keyword.

Also, put your class SMSMain in it's own file SMSMain.java. Then import the needed classes (ctrl-shift-o in Eclipse).

Try to always put a class in it's own file, unless you've got a really good reason not to.

Comment: when i put static then it gives this error: Illegal static declaration in inner class na.edu.pon.oop210s.s12012.s211045888.sms.sms.Student.lecturer.course.SMSMain
  modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations

Answer (score 0):

You main class **must** be static.

Like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // main goes here
}
```

Comment: is the method that must be static

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `public  void main(String[] args) {` with `public static void main(String[] args) {`

Answer (score 0):

Your coding style is confusing.    Learn the Oracle/Sun Java coding standards.

The main method has to follow the exact signature and be associated with the public outer class, not one of the inner classes.

```
package na.edu.pon.oop210s.s12012.s211045888.sms;

/**
 * Student Number: <211045888>
 * Date: 3/11/12 7:47 pM
 * Exercise: <Exercise 4>
 * Created using: <netbeans>
 */

// bad naming.  What's sms?  student management system?  sado-masochistic society?
public class sms {      
    public static void main(String [] args) { 
    }
}
```